# Replace ivygen leaf cards with custom leaves

Tags: modeling, add-on

is there anyway to replace the leaf cards that ivygen generates with custom modeled and textured leaves (a group) but keeping the original orientations of the leaf cards from ivygen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most often you don't want to do that: think about the amount of polygons that would be. (You could kinda get away with it if you work with Ivygen at a small scale. Good luck with doing it with a tree in the Sapling add-on...)

The smart way as long as the camera is far enough to get away with it is to alpha map the leaves. (I believe they are UV unwrapped by default, I could be mistaken.) This reduces the poly but gives you a greater amount of detail.

If you want an example of this technique out in the wild, have a look at this piece from blenderartists: http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?382855-Fairytale-Village

If the camera is too close for a pure alpha map, you may want to use dupliobject (and specifically duplifaces) to give it some depth. These approaches can be mixed: the exact outline of the leaf can be done using alpha maps to save on polygons. For duplifaces, see here: You could use dupliobjects. See here: http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.4/Manual/Modeling/Objects/Duplication/DupliFaces

Comment: the problem with using the default leaf cards is that they are flat and so don't look realistic. I've even watched kent tramell's tutorial on varying the color of leaves, that's not the problem. I don't mind a bit of lag in the viewport and blender can handle high polycounts these days very well. so to achieve just that bit more realism i would like to replace the ivygen leaves with the ones i've modeled.

Comment: You could use dupliobjects. See here: http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.4/Manual/Modeling/Objects/Duplication/DupliFaces

Comment: That worked, thanks :) It was easier than I thought it would be.

Comment: Could you mark this as solved?

Comment: If it was dupli objects that solved the problem, this shouldn't be marked as solved. The answer it's self misunderstands the problem. btw, I hear that it takes longer to calculate the alpha of all the leaves then it does to just render a leaf with several poly's and no alpha.

Comment: @TARDISMaker I don't have too solid evidence about it, but my point was that the 3D view would turn into syrup. I will try to make the dupli approach visible in the answer.

Comment: @TARDISMaker I found using alpha maps slows down render time compared to using non-alpha modeled leaves, even with the transparency depth trick. that was another reason why I wanted this approach. but the problem ivygen has then is that all the leaves face the same direction it seems. it just looks unrealistic. there should be an option to give the leaves some random rotation